# FLUTTER | How to add data to an existing document in firestore

Tags: firebase, dart, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-firestore, flutter

I'm using firestore to store data of my flutter application, and I made a function that creates a document in firestore automatically  after the user login

[image: My Firestore database]
[image]

Now I want the user when he fills this form , the data will be added in the same document where the user's email exists.

```
RaisedButton(
              child: Text("Submit"),
              onPressed: () {
               final CollectionReference users = Firestore.instance.collection('users');
                Firestore.instance
                    .runTransaction((Transaction transaction) async {
                  CollectionReference reference =
                  Firestore.instance.collection('users');

                  await reference
                      .add({"fullname": nameController.text, "PhoneNumber": phoneController.text, "adresse": adressController.text});
                  nameController.clear();
                  phoneController.clear();
                  adressController.clear();

                });}
```

I tried this code but it adds new document.

Comment: your problem is with what file are you trying to update. You need to get correct reference of your file. Do you know what file do you want to update?

Answer (score 19):

Specify document name before updating database.

```dart
Firestore.instance
  .collection('Products')
    .document('Apple')
      .updateData({
        'price': 120, 
        'quantity': 15
      });
```

Here my price and quantity data are numbers. If yours are `String`s put `String` values there.

Comment: there's also the option of ```instance.collection('users').document('${user.id}').setData({"fullname": nameController.text, "PhoneNumber": phoneController.text, "adresse": adressController.text});
```

Comment: setData will delete the existing document and create a new one. The question is not about that. It's about adding data to an existing document.

Answer (score 7):

Best practice is to use transaction.
Make sure that document reference is a reference to a file that you wish to update.

```
            Firestore.instance.runTransaction((transaction) async {
              await transaction.update(
                  documentReference, data);
            };
```

It will make sure that update happens in order in case there are many clients doing it.

In the case of a concurrent edit, Cloud Firestore runs the entire transaction again. For example, if a transaction reads documents and another client modifies any of those documents, Cloud Firestore retries the transaction. This feature ensures that the transaction runs on up-to-date and consistent data.

More info [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions)

Answer (score 7):

Try `.setData({"fullname": nameController.text, "PhoneNumber": phoneController.text, "adresse": adressController.text}, merge: true)`.

Comment: `updateData()` did not work for me. I mean it worked but it replaced the whole data. `setData()` with `merge: true` worked perfectly for me.

Answer (score 2):

#### Update 2021:

You need to update the data to add it to an existing document.

```dart
var collection = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users');
collection 
    .doc('doc_id') // <-- Doc ID where data should be updated.
    .update({'age' : 20}) // <-- New data
    .then((_) => print('Updated'))
    .catchError((error) => print('Update failed: $error'));
```