# How to filter Stream client side for a specific document in firestore?

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I'm serving up a stream from a collection in *Firestore*. The collection is called *users*. There is one document in the collection called *stats* which is basically used as a counter for the amount of documents in the collection. The other documents are all the same, basic info to build a list of cards in the frontend with a *StreamBuilder*.

```
Widget _buildContents(BuildContext context) {
    final database = Provider.of<Database>(context);
    return StreamBuilder<List<User>>(
      stream: database.usersStream(),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        return ListItemsBuilder<User>(
          snapshot: snapshot,
          itemBuilder: (context, user) => UserListTile(user:user), //would like to pass counter value to `UserListTile`
        );
      },
    );
  }
```

I want to know how to filter the stream client side for the stats document and retrieve the counter value in the collection and pass it to `UserListTile`

Comment: As I understand, you're using a [distributed counter](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/counters) to get the number of documents in your your _users_ collection. You can retrieve the counter value stored in the document using something like `Firestore.instance.collection('users').document("stats").get();`. This will allow you to read in the _stats_ document's content and get the count integer that you can store in a variable. Now, I'm not sure what _UserListTitle_ is in your database structure, but if you want to add some data into an existing document, you can follow this

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50559148/flutter-how-to-add-data-to-an-existing-document-in-firestore